# Add UIPageViewController in present app

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have an app in working state in which I have a three screens 1,2,3 each of that screen is associated with a `UICollectionView` which are created programatically now I want to modify the current implementation & add those collection views to UIPageViewControllers.

I tried to find many tutorials related to PageViewController with CollectionViews but was not able to find anything. Can anyone help me out in implementing this or can give me a reference related to this.

I have also referred [this tutorial](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/), but hard luck for me :(

Comment: What is the problem ? PageViewController behaves like any other UIViewController.

Comment: Actually what I now want is the animation provided by Page view controller on swiping left & right. currently I am just creating & loading the collection view in that view controller, if I implement that I will be able to get that animation.

Comment: Just place the collection view inside each page ?

Comment: Can you please give any reference so that I can follow those steps & can achieve my goal

Comment: I think you are overthinking it - I don't know your setup but a PageViewController will just display a number of pages in a scrollview - what you place there is entirely up to you - it doesnt matter if its a collectionview or anything else

Comment: @pe60t0: Sorry to disturb you again, but I am not able to do it, maybe I am over confused. Can you please help me out with a sample code.

Comment: Can you post some more details on what exactly you want to do ? And some code of what you have so far.

Comment: I just want that much help that you create a sample application which contains 3 collection views & embedded in UIPageViewController in swift, rest I will do.

Comment: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

Comment: I have already saw that buddy but I want one which shows collection views

Comment: A collection view is just a view ! It doesn't matter if what you put inside each page.

Comment: Just follow [one](http://www.makemegeek.com/uipageviewcontroller-example-ios/) [of](http://swiftiostutorials.com/ios-tutorial-using-uipageviewcontroller-create-content-slider-objective-cswift/) [the](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_7_UIPageViewController_Application) [many](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) tutorials on `UIPageViewController` and where they insert the view controller / view insert a `UICollectionViewController` / `UICollectionView`.

Comment: Why the down vote? Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just follow some of those page view controller tutorials, and when you get to the point of instantiating the child view controllers, make those children collection view controllers. Just as in your example tutorial where it is using `UIImageView` try replacing it with `UICollectionViews` & you will achieve what you want.

Do tell if you face any difficulties.
Happy Coding!

Comment: Oh!!! Ya... Yes it seems working.... Will surely disturb you if I will be in any problem. Thank you BTW. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by:

1)  Subclassing `UIPageViewController` and conforming to the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol. The data source will tell the pageViewController which view controllers will come next or before the current view controller being presented.

2) In `viewDidLoad()`, set the `dataSource` as `self` so the delegate methods get called. Also, call `self.setViewControllers([collectionViewController], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)`. `collectionViewController` will be an array populated with 1 collection view controller (the first view controller presented).

Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dataSource = self   //so our delegate methods get called

    //use tags to reference each controller
    let collectionViewOne = TestCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionViewOne.view.tag = 0
    let collectionViewTwo = TestCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionViewTwo.view.tag = 1
    let collectionViewThree = TestCollectionViewController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    collectionViewThree.view.tag = 2

    collectionViewControllers = [collectionViewOne, collectionViewTwo, collectionViewThree]

    self.setViewControllers([collectionViewOne], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

3) Implement the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` methods:

```
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = viewController.view.tag

    if index == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    if index > 0 {
        index--
    }
    return collectionViewControllers[index] as? TestCollectionViewController
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = viewController.view.tag

    if index == 2 {
        return nil
    }

    if index < collectionViewControllers.count - 1 {
        index++
    }
    return collectionViewControllers[index] as? TestCollectionViewController
}
```

We return `nil` if the index will present an out of bounds view controller

Source code of `TestCollectionViewController` and the `UIPageViewController` subclass can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/BenJamminnn/f07964a6817e2b5c3fce)

Comment: Your answer is also good but not suitable for me, might be it can help some other person.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar situation recently. I could never get the embedded `UICollectionView`s to work quite how I wanted them to in the `UIPageViewController`. I also felt that the implementation was overly complex, requiring a separate view controller for each `UICollectionView`. I did not feel this was appropriate for my dataset.

My solution was to use a single `UIViewController` with a horizontally scrolling, paged `UICollectionView` to handle the paging. Then I added vertically scrolling `UICollectionView`s for every page to contain my content. I also added an overlay that contained a `UIPageControl` that was fed scroll-position data to mock the page indicator. This vastly simplified my view controller to data source relationship, was easier to customize, and allowed greater control.

(I would post source but the code belongs to my employer and I used storyboards.)